# SD Card messed up

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb, recovery-mode, external-sd

I had recently partitioned my SDCARD to work with my phone. Added an EXT4 and FAT32 partitions. After a power failure the data got corrupted. I can still see it but it's not the same as before. I've tried the following programs:
dd
fsck 
e2fsck 
fsck.ext4 Works but doesn't do anything. After a relaod of the card still shows the  same.Applies to all of the above 
palimpset -- Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sdd1 : I/O Error 
gparted -- Attempt to write sectors 128-128 outside of partition on /dev/sdd 
None helped.
So my question is. What can i use to make it work again. Any low-level formatting tools? Can my card be somehow in R/O mode?
Also ClockworkMod Recovery seems to not be able to partition/format it. It just says it completed the operation but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Using a card reader, try [HP's Disk Storage Format tool](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197)

I use this to reformat fake overcapacity flash disks to proper size before and it made my kingston 4gb usb work again after getting corrupted.

Comment: Failed to format the device :(